# In Android how to get the profile pic of the user that has signed in

Tags: android

I want to get the profile pic of the signed in user.I use the following function. The user name is returned, but the profile pic in variable mIcon11 is returning null.

```
String username;
Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            username = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();

            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(personPhotoUrl).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am setting an imageview and textview in my screen as follows

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
textview.setText(username);
```

The text is getting printed, but the image is null.Where did I go wrong in my code. Please help me!!

Comment: signed into googleplay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                System.out.println(personPhoto);
                //We can adjust size of image according to our requirements: here 200 is the size of image
                String personImage=personPhoto.substring(0,personPhoto.lastIndexOf("=")+1)+"200";
                System.out.println(personImage);

            }
```

You will get image of the url in personImage String and then you can load it using Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

Picasso.with(context).load(personImage).into(imageview);

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer, but my app does not work a lot with images, and I just needed the pic to display as a profile pic in my app. Do I still need to do it in a separate thread and do I need to download Picasso. Will it make my app very heavy?

Comment: no it will not make app heavy at all, instead it allows you to cache images rather than downloading images on separate thread again and again, you can also use callbacks in picasso as well as change size images and transform them

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in separate thread.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView image;

  public DownloadImageTask(ImageView image) {
      this.image = image;
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      // Do downloading stuff
      return bitmap;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      image.setImageBitmap(result);
  }
}
```

It will be so simple if you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) libraries.

With Picasso, its as simple as this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(personPhotoUrl).into(imageview);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer, but my app does not work a lot with images, and I just needed the pic to display as a profile pic in my app. Do I still need to do it in a separate thread and do I need to download Picasso. Will it make my app very heavy?

Comment: I would always suggested a separate thread for network activities. But my suggestion will be Picasso. Its hardly 120 KB. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.2/picasso-2.5.2.jar. Major advantage of using that would be efficient memory handling of bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Loading data from server should always be done off the UI thread. You can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html or open source libraries like glide, picasso ..